# Learning prolog - Getting error { >/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated.}

Tags: prolog

```
Nrs_Between(X,Y,Nr) :-
    Z>X,
    Z<Y,
    Nr is Z.
```

-------------------------*-----------------------------

```
?- Nrs_Between(1,10,X).
```

Waiting for output:

```
Z = 2;
Z = 3;
etc
```

Getting output:

```
>/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated.
```

-------------------------*-----------------------------

Anyone?

Comment: Your code is syntactically invalid. So I doubt you actually get the output you claim you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `</2` and `>/2` evaluate arithmetic expressions. They do not take free variables.

Classical solution: use [`between/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=between/3).

```
?- between(1, 3, X).
X = 1 ;
X = 2 ;
X = 3.
```

Another option: use [CLP(FD)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpfd).

```
?- X #>= 1, X #=< 3, label([X]).
X = 1 ;
X = 2 ;
X = 3.
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I know I can use between, but I could not find how to filter out only even numbers from range... And that is the real problem.

Comment: @FiedbergNichenko You should re-formulate your question then. Like, ask a new one or edit the one you have asked. It would be silly to answer your real question, asked as a comment, in a comment. And make sure you give your question a descriptive title. Make sure you read [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @FiedbergNichenko The point is, both solutions above are one step away from getting only odd numbers as solutions. But this is not at all what your question is about....